# SQL Server : conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to import a table into SQL Server and executing the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO [schemes] 
VALUES('3510C197C4043E419C8F01E0C62FA978', 1, 'AS2', null, 
       '2009-04-21 12:52:00.000', '2009-04-21 12:52:00.000');
```

I am getting an exception

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: It is not a GUID. GUID has a format.

Comment: Post the 'schemes' structure

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert it on a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` in the right format, for sample:

```
DECLARE @uuid VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @gid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

SET @uuid = '3510C197C4043E419C8F01E0C62FA978'
SELECT @gid = CAST(
        SUBSTRING(@uuid, 1, 8) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uuid, 9, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uuid, 13, 4) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING(@uuid, 17, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@uuid, 21, 12)
        AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

and after it, insert this value

```
insert into [schemes] 
values(@gid, 1, 'AS2', null, '2009-04-21 12:52:00.000', '2009-04-21 12:52:00.000');
```